# Electron App Loops Restaring Itself on Windows

Tags: node.js, electron

It is working fine on macOS but on Windows upon launching it loops itself quit & restart with no error or stop. I can see the UI for a second or two.

`electron .` or `npm start`

Here is my main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
var server = require('./localServer');
var uploader = require('./ftpUploader');

var window;
try {
  require('electron-reloader')(module);
} catch (err) {}
electron.app.on('ready', function() {
  window = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    width: 1600,
    height: 950,
    webPreferences: {
      experimentalFeatures: true,
    }
  });
  window.webContents.openDevTools();
  window.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Comment: Anything on the console? Might be helpful if you added `package.json` contents as well.

Comment: I'd suggest requiring `electron-log` and then trying to write logs in a couple different places. Make sure you're writing them as `error` logs so you can see them easily.